# Get a Array subset without copying like in C with pointers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an api call which needs to get a `byte[]` as parameter and my data already is in a `byte[]`. The problem is that I want to send this buffer in little chunks.

The slow solution would be to copy the array data to new arrays. But I don't want to do this because copying is unnecessary. I just want a `byte[]`-pointer which i can move around in my buffer. Like in C or C++...

Here a sample in pseudo code:

```
ArrayOriginal = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 100 }
```

`ArrayFirstChunk = { 0, 1, 2 }` (pointer to the first element in the Original Array)
`ArraySecondChunk = { 3, 4, 5 }` (pointer to the fourth element in the Original Array)
...

Is this possible? The data shall be available only one time in the memory.

thx

Comment: *"But I don't want to do this because copying is unnecessary."* Have you identified this as a performance issue, or are you optimizing prematurely? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say whether you can change the API. I assume not, but if you can, there is always `IEnumerable<byte>` - so you return

```
myarray.Skip(4).Take(4);
```

etc

Comment: +1 great answer :) There is an ArraySegment class in the framework but it's not used much, and this method is much nicer

Comment: you can call ToArray() again on the end of the Linq chain but this would create a copy

Comment: ok yes with ToArray() it works but is the data copied with this command?

Comment: yes ToArray would create a new array with the filtered elements.. are you sure copying/creating the array is really a performance issue for you? Have you profiled this?

Comment: no I made no performance tests but I want to send very large files with this technique and since I am coming from the embedded world I thought that there must be a solution for this to just point to a subset of an array. thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `unsafe` to get a pointer to your array. Otherwise [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) is an efficient way of copying portions of arrays to another array. If sending small chunks of data you could just reuse the small array instance and leave it to garbage collection to release the memory from the array.

Comment: This is just horrible advice.  There is no reason in this case to use unsafe code.  I would argue there is no reason to split the Array, and I would hardly call Buffer.BlockCopy effective

Comment: @Ramhound the OP has (comments) stated that the API will only *accept* a `byte[]`, and if the OP wants to send it in little pieces then re-using and over-writing (via `BlockCopy`) a buffer is probably the only way left to the OP. Effective or not, copying will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create FakeArray that contain an array an offset and a length. Like this you could work with subarray of array. But It won't be an array.

Comment: Like MattDavey said above, this is essentially what ArraySegment does. So no need to create 'FakeArray' - but you are quite right it is still not an array type.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array as a parameter, you are passing just a pointer to that array. **The array is stored only once in memory.**
So, I think you just don't need to divide in little chunks.
If you want to process it in chunks, I would suggest just reading the desired elements, first from 0 to 2, then from 3 to 5, etc...

Hope that helps

Comment: I think the gist of the question is that he cannot change the API or it's behaviour - so can't return the array and an 'offset' etc

Comment: Well, if that's the case maybe the API expects a size as a parameter and he can read the whole array in one call.

Comment: I've achieved something similar in the past by writing an 'ArrayIterator' object which is constructed with an offset & a length which wraps access to the original array. Effective but does require changing the API

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of handling data inside an array is simply to specify a chosen offset and count, for example:

```
// {0, ..., 100}
byte[] data = Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
Write(data, 0, 3);
Write(data, 3, 3);
...
static void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    for(int i = offset ; i < offset + count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(buffer[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can do something similar to the C approach with `unsafe` (via `byte*` and `fixed`), but I'm not sure it buys you much here; but:

```
fixed(byte* ptr = data)
{
    Write(ptr, 3);
    Write(ptr + 3, 3);
}
...
static unsafe void Write(byte* ptr, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(ptr[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can *encapsulate* a buffer, offset and count, but then it won't *be* an array - probably not very helpful.

Comment: I don't think that this really can help since I have to give the api call a byte[]. Anyway thx

Comment: @fpdragon k then see my comment on Phill's answer