# C#, get a sub-part of array without copying the data (like having C pointers)

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array with data like this (managed code)

```
byte[] test = {0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD}; // data is much longer...
```

If I explicit do like this, LINQ will create a copy from original array.

```
var test2 = test.Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray();
```

and I need a part of it, but without creating a copy as new array.

Inspired by this,
[Get a Array subset without copying like in C with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008763/get-a-array-subset-without-copying-like-in-c-with-pointers)

```
var test2 = test.Skip(1).Take(2);
```

it works, but the result is IEnumerable and I need a pure byte[].

So basically the goal is to have a real chunk of original array (not a copy of chunk) and if I modify a element, to be reflected in chunk too (like having pointers in C)

Is it possible to convert IEnumerable to byte[] without copy?
Is it possible to do it otherwise (no LINQ)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a pure `byte[]`?

Comment: Have a look at `Memory<byte>` and `Span<byte>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0) or `Memory<byte>`:

```
byte[] test = { 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD };

// Span is some kind of c-like pointer to the array
// first  2 - skip 2 items
// second 2 - take 2 items
Span<byte> span = new Span<byte>(test, 2, 2);

// We modify the array item...
test[3] = 0xFF;

// ... and span reflects the modification 
// Note that we have skipped 2 items, that's why span[1], not span[3]
byte result = span[1]; // 0xFF
```

Comment: Note that you can write `test.AsSpan(2, test.Length - 2)` instead of `new Span<byte>(test, 2, test.Length - 2);`

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I am looking for :)) hope that is working on .NET 4.8 (VS 2015). Big thanks!

Comment: @orfruit It's possible to make it work on .NET 4.8 but you will have to import the `System.Memory` NuGet package.

Comment: I did, works, but however Span<T> is not supported by compiler. I also have VS2019 and it works. Thanks a lot again! Apparently, it was about time to move to VS2019...